# Error with example in Hypertable

Tags: java, hypertable

i have a code in Java languaje and I'm using a example of Hypertable but i have a error.

The code is:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import org.hypertable.thrift.*;
import org.hypertable.thriftgen.*;

public class HypertableJDBCTester 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        ThriftClient client = null;
        long ns = -1;
        Schema schema = new Schema();
        HqlResult resultQuery = null;
        HqlResultAsArrays result_as_arrays = null;

        try {

            client = ThriftClient.create("localhost", 38080);
            if (!client.namespace_exists("test"))
                client.namespace_create("test");
            ns = client.namespace_open("test");

            client.table_drop(ns, "Fruits", true);
            client.table_create(ns, "Fruits", schema);

            Map column_families = new HashMap();

            ColumnFamilySpec cf = new ColumnFamilySpec();
            cf.setName("genus");
            column_families.put("genus", cf);

            cf = new ColumnFamilySpec();
            cf.setName("tag");
            column_families.put("tag", cf);

            cf = new ColumnFamilySpec();
            cf.setName("description");
            column_families.put("description", cf);

            schema.setColumn_families(column_families);

            resultQuery = client.hql_exec(ns, "INSERT INTO Fruits VALUES ('strawberry','genus', 'Fragaria')", true, false);

            result_as_arrays  = client.hql_query_as_arrays(ns, "SELECT * from Fruits WHERE ROW = 'lemon'");
            for (List<String> cell_as_array : result_as_arrays.cells)
                System.out.println(cell_as_array.subList(0, 4));

            client.namespace_close(ns);
        }
        catch (ClientException e) {
          System.out.println(e.message);
          System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

The output is

```
HYPERTABLE bad key - namespace=1791095845 hql=INSERT INTO Fruits VALUES ('strawberry','genus', 'Fragaria') noflush=1 unbuffered=0.
```

What is my problem??

Comment: Please show us your DB tables structure.

Comment: It's empty. In the code I have the create.